# Can a Django model's choices be mapped to classes that are not models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization

I've got a bunch of MealIngredient models which have a foreign key of UnitChoice like so:

```
class MealIngredient(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(IngredientUnit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)], default=1)

class IngredientUnit(models.Model):
UNIT_CHOICES = [
        ('Imperial', (
                (Volume.pinch, 'pinch'),
                (Volume.teaspoon, 'teaspoon'),
                (Volume.tablespoon, 'tablespoon'),
                (Volume.fluidOunce, 'fluid ounce'),
                (Volume.cup, 'cup'),
                (Volume.pint, 'pint'),
                (Volume.quart, 'quart'),
                (Volume.gallon, 'gallon'),
                (Mass.ounce, 'ounce'),
                (Mass.pound, 'pound'),
            )
         ),
        ('Metric', (
                (Volume.milliliter, 'milliliter'),
                (Volume.centiliter, 'centiliter'),
                (Volume.deciliter, 'deciliter'),
                (Volume.liter, 'liter'),
                (Volume.decaliter, 'decaliter'),
                (Volume.hectoliter, 'hectoliter'),
                (Volume.kiloliter, 'kiloliter'),
                (Mass.gram, 'gram'),
                (Mass.kilogram, 'kilogram'),
            )
         ),
        ('individual', 'individual')
    ]
unit_choice = models.CharField(choices=UNIT_CHOICES, default='individual', max_length=20)
```

I've imported 'sugarcube' which lets you define units, conversions, etc.
My issue is that the classes imported from sugarcube (Volume, Mass, etc.) are not models, and as such I'm getting:

> ValueError: Cannot serialize: pinch
> There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.

Is there a way to make this work? Can I make sugarcube's classes serializable?

Comment: Considering that `Volume.pinch`, etc. are objects of a class `Unit` you keeping them as values that will be stored in the database don't make sense anyway. Why not simply store their names, so `Volume.pinch.name`?

Comment: with them as a Unit I can directly do things like '(2 * Volume.cup * Element('water')).to(Volume.milliliter)' >>> 480 ml water. As just a name, I still have to map them back to Units elsewhere to do so. If that's the best way, I can still do it, I was just hoping for something simpler.

Comment: I think you should *swap* the keys and the values, so `('milliliter', Volume.milliliter)`, since the `'mililiter'` is the item that will be stored in the database., and the `Volume.mililiter` the thing you use for calculus.